# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/formula/udf/UDFFinder error in java

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi, wildfly-10

hi i am writing a excel using apache poi.I am using SXSSFWorkbook for it.But when this code executes i am getting this error again and again.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/formula/udf/UDFFinder

my sample code is

```
Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(); // i am getting error here
        SXSSFSheet s = (SXSSFSheet)wb.createSheet("Import List");
```

and dependency which i am using for this is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
```

now please give me some solution to resolve this
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your poi jar version is not matching the poi-ooxml jar version

`poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL` depends on `poi-3.10-FINAL`

You either remove dependency on poi as poi-ooxml brings needed version or add proper version for poi